# Calculate days since a timestamp?

Tags: php

This one works for dates in format: 0000-00-00

But I need a function for unix timestamp format

```
function dateDiff($start, $end) {

    $start_ts = strtotime($start);

    $end_ts = strtotime($end);

    $diff = $end_ts - $start_ts;

    return round($diff / 86400);

}
```

Could anyone help a brother out??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of calculating the timestamps from the two dates received as parameters, you could just receive those timestamps as parameters directly ; ie, just remove the calls to strtotime.

Something like this should do the trick, I suppose :

```
function dateDiffTs($start_ts, $end_ts) {
    $diff = $end_ts - $start_ts;
    return round($diff / 86400);
}
```

Afterall, [strotime](http://php.net/strtotime) gets you the timestamp corresponding to a date ;-)

For instance, this :

```
var_dump(dateDiffTs(1251151200, 1251410400));
```

get you 3 days *(1251151200 is 2009-08-25, and 1251410400 is 2009-08-28)*.

And this works if you have hours in the timestamps too :

```
var_dump(dateDiffTs(1251196200, 1251443700));
```

Gets you 3 days too *(1251196200 is 2009-08-25 12:30:00 and 1251443700 is 2009-08-28 09:15:00)*.

Comment: This is not exactly correct, due to DST considerations that make some days 23/25 hours long